# Renaming pandas columns gives not found in index error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame called `v` where columns are = `['self','id','desc','name','arch','rel']`. And when I rename is as follows it won't let me drop columns giving `column not found in axis` error.

case1:

```
for i in range(0,len(v.columns)):
   #I'm trying to add 'v_' prefix to all col names
   v.columns.values[i] = 'v_' + v.columns.values[i]

v.drop('v_self',1)

#leads to error
KeyError: "['v_self'] not found in axis"
```

But if I do it as follows then it works fine

case2:

```
v.columns = ['v_self','v_id','v_desc','v_name','v_arch','v_rel']
v.drop('v_self',1)
# no error
```

In both cases if I do following it give same results for its columns

```
v.columns
#both cases gives 
Index(['v_self', 'v_id', 'v_description', 'v_name', 'v_archived',
   'v_released'],
  dtype='object')
```

I can't understand why in the case1 it gives an error? Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `.values` returns the underlying values. You're not supposed to change those directly. Assigning directly to `.columns` is supported though.

Try something like this:

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    [
        {key: 0 for key in ["self", "id", "desc", "name", "arch", "rel"]}
        for _ in range(100)
    ]
)

# Add a v_ to every column
df.columns = [f"v_{column}" for column in df.columns]

# Drop one column
df = df.drop(columns=["v_self"])
```

Comment: Yes!, this is the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

**To your "case 1":**

You meet a bug ([#38547](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/38547)) in pandas — “Direct renaming of 1 column seems to be accepted, but only old name is working”.

> It means that after that "renaming", you may delete the first column
> **not** by using
>
> ```
> v.drop('v_self',1)
> ```
>
> but **using the old name**
>
> ```
> v.drop('self',1)`.
> ```
>
> Of course, the better option is not using such a buggy renaming in the
> current versions of pandas.

---

**To renaming columns by adding a prefix to every label:**

There is a direct dateframe method `.add_prefix()` for it, isn't it?

```
v = df.add_prefix("v_")
```